# I cant parse summer note rich text editor with node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, summernote

I know how to use the req.body.name to get text values from the front end. I cant figure out how to get the contents in my summer note to my Node JS server. How can I fix this problem?

I am asscessing the contents inside the summer notw WYSIWYG editor with this code in node js: req.body.editor.

I get undefined as the result.

Comment: Should i ask my magic 8 ball? Post some code... Complete the tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour, read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I Found d solution. I Used textarea instead of div.